# Have my LEDs failed over time?

Tags: led, failure, component-failure

I installed 6 battery-powered 1Watt LEDS in my dad's home to help when he has power outages. They worked as intended for some time, but recently begun to fail in an odd way. They no longer turn on immediately, instead seem to slowly warm up. At their brightest they are still incredibly dim. One seems to flicker dimly, while another does not turn on at all. I've never seen LEDs fail in this way (if it even is the LEDs at all)

Here is the schematic:
[image]

If I remember correctly, the LEDs where 1W ±3V. Something like this: [Datasheet](http://wayjun.com/Datasheet/Led/High%20Brightness%201W%20High%20Power%20White%20LED.pdf)

My dad says over time the lights began to act erratically. Eventually half the lights stopped working, then a few weeks later they all stopped working (which makes sense considering I've got two strings of three).
I suspect one dud LED failed leading to a cascade of the rest failing, or mice chewing the wires in the ceiling.

The battery is measuring 13.7V

One of the LEDs measured 2.36V. This was after it had eventually "warmed up" and was shining very dimly. It was not warm to the touch like they were when they shone at full brightness. (Didn't measure the rest because its high up in the ceiling. I'm assuming they're all reading ±2.36V)

R1 = 8ohm (To limit current to ±660 mA)

R2 is a few ohms. Shouldn't effect the circuit.

What do you think the issue is? Has anyone experienced LEDs slowly failing over time in this manner? Will it be worthwhile replacing the LEDs, or do you thing they will fail in time again?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Get a proper constant controlled LED driver (Switching preferably, not linear). Your system will be much more reliable and the battery will also last longer. Depending on the driver you might also get cheap/easy dimming capability.

Comment: LED thermal runaway due to the single R1?  LTSPice will not have simulated that.

Comment: Try putting the LEDs in parallel and putting a bigger resistance next time.

Comment: also attach a heatsink with the LED, make sure the LED's are from a top notch company, chinese LED's have a tendency to act erroneously...

Comment: The shared current limiting resistor means that when one diode fails the other 5 will be overloaded and probably eventually damaged. My guess is one of the diodes failed (either open or short) and then damaged the others.

Comment: The 12V battery is probably 13.8V and three series 3V LEDs are 9V. Then the total current is (13.8V - 9V)/8 ohms= 600mA. Then each series string gets 300mA and dissipates 9V x 300mA= 900mW. Each LED dissipates 300mW and needs additional heatsinking.

Answer (score 3):

You may have damaged LEDs. Do not connect LED in parallel. They are not exactly equal. Two separate resistors for each row value 12 Ohm 2W should be.Due to some inequality in LED one row may have current bigger than another. It will damage LEDs. After they gone and not conduct current second row is damaged because of excessive current. And that kind of diodes require heatsink, that small PCBs not enough to dissipate heat